# how to get server ip of PPP connection

Tags: perl

After establishing a PPP connection using rasdial (making a dial-up call), how do I get the 'server ip' address that is given to me. It's usually a local ip, but I cannot seem to get it when I do an ipconfig.

However I can see this IP address, if I right click on the connection and select status.

This question has been asked in the past, but by .NET and C# users and their solution is using  a certain available library, which I don't have.

Does anyone know how to obtain the PPP server ip? I need that IP address to initiate an FTP traffic with the modem.

I established the connection this way :

```
system (rasdial [connection_name]);  # in perl.
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you link to the .NET questions?

Comment: Are you performing the [IPCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Control_Protocol) yourself?

Answer (score 0):

I think your best best is to hook into the [Windows API calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [Win32::API](http://search.cpan.org/~cosimo/Win32-API-0.68/API.pm).  You probably want to start with [RasEnumConnections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).